# product_links not working

Tags: python, odoo

i am trying to install product_links module in opernerp 6.1 in order to intergrate magento with openerp. When i try to install product_links i came up with this error.

```
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 180, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(controller, self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1004, in call_button
    action = self.call_common(req, model, method, args, domain_id, context_id)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 948, in call_common
    return self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 962, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 250, in proxy
    args, kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/common/openerplib/main.py", line 117, in proxy
    result = self.connector.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 611, in send
    raise fault


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/web/common/http.py", line 592, in send
    result = openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/netsvc.py", line 360, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 572, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 167, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 121, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 176, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 164, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_upgrade.py", line 101, in upgrade_module
    _db, pool = pooler.restart_pool(cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/pooler.py", line 39, in restart_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.new(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, True)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 160, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 338, in load_modules
    processed = load_marked_modules(cr, graph, states_to_load, force, status, report, loaded_modules)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 253, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 165, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/module.py", line 409, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/modules/module.py", line 139, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/product_links/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import product_links
  File "/opt/openerp/openerp-6.1-1/openerp/addons/product_links/product_links.py", line 24, in <module>
    class product_link(external_osv.external_osv):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'external_osv'
```

Can anybody help me???

Comment: Which branch of product_links and magentoerpconnect are you using?

Comment: i have checked it out from trunk.

Answer (score 1):

There are two stable branches of the Magento openerp connector: stable and oldstable.

For **stable**, use  lp:magentoerpconnect/oerp6.1-stable and the following dependency branches

- lp:e-commerce-addons/oerp6.1-stable
- lp:openobject-extension/oerp6.1-stable
- lp:product-extra-addons/oerp6.1-stable

For **oldstable**, use  lp:magentoerpconnect/oerp6.1-oldstable and the following dependency branches:

- lp:c2c-ecom-addons/6.1
- lp:extra-addons/trunk

Don't use trunk unless you want to contribute to the development of magentoerpconnect.

Comment: There is problem with 6.1 in integrating magento. WE used 6.0 and its working fine.